# Adding a AWS Lambda between API Gateway and Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, polyglot

I have a team that has built everything using NodeJS/Typescript. They have specific libraries that are written in typescript that can read the headers the upstream services pass.

However, my service is in Spring boot which of course is a JVM service. Now, I want to use this typescript library to extract headers from request and pass to my controller. What are my options?

I have compiled a couple of them:

1. [NOT SURE] I assume there must be a way to add a AWS Lambda that massages the request and sits between API Gateway and my spring boot app. This lambda can act as the authorizer lambda which can clean and forward the request to spring boot. I am thinking of this lambda more like an interceptor rather than a proxy.
2. Polyglot programming. Not sure how to do that. Anyone has any idea how can i use a typescript library in java?

Any suggestions, opinions will be appreciated!

Comment: If I had to do it I would port the code to java, or expose it via http (if possible). You can probably do the thing with the lambda I don't see any reason why it won't work, but it sound like an overcomplicated solution. For option 2 you can explore graalVM it can run JS code in the jvm

Comment: Agreed. I just decided to rewrite library in java. Thanks for the heads up!